# Updating a photo in a certain period by html automatically

Tags: html, photos

I have one free website (e.g. wordpress, weebly etc.) and I am generating one figure after every certain time (e.g. 10 mins) in my PC using the same file name. Now in my free website I have an option to write html code and I want to upload my updated photos automatically by this html code in every 10 minutes. How can I do that?

I want it to be automatically updated without any assistance from user, so that when a user enters the website she can see the updated figure.

Comment: please show what u have generated till now

Comment: @NitinVarpe: I am new in html and after analyzing what I found was updating a standalone webpage by <img src="nameofpic.jpg" > but it does not work with a file stored in PC and found this code can work if I have already uploaded my photo in some where else as well. For either cases my situation does not match.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want your website to update every 10 min. If you write HTML:

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="refreshing number... example(every 4 seconds, write  4)
</head>
```